# How to increase the disk space of Ubuntu installed besides dual boot without using WUBI?

Tags: disk, resize

I want to increase the disk space on the partition that the Ubuntu installed in.

I wonder about doing this in windows or in Ubuntu? The rest free space is less than 300MB.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reduce the size of your Windows partition, I recommend doing this in **Windows**.

To re-size your Ubuntu partition, I recommend using **Ubuntu live CD/DVD/USB** and **Gparted Partition Editor**. When you're at it you can also re-size other partitions although you can do in from the installed Ubuntu as well.